# Why is NSwag/Swagger scheme set to only HTTP when I publish to a server but on my local machine it is HTTPS?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, nswag

Works find locally. Using ASP.NET core 3.1

Publish to dev I notice the swagger only has HTTP option and when I try a GET on a service I get below?

Is there something on the dev server that is causing this that I need to change ?

SEC7111: [Mixed-Content] The origin 'https://corerd.rb.gov' was loaded in a secure context but tried to load an insecure  resource at 'http://corerd.rb.gov/PWDRS/api/TestWebApi'.

No Results

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.. Though still don't know why it defaults to HTTP

```
app.UseOpenApi(configure => configure.PostProcess = (document, _) => document.Schemes = new[] { NSwag.OpenApiSchema.Https });
```

Comment: I think somehow aspnet core reports that the server is running on http - simplest solution is actually what you did...

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, setting the Schemes to `null` disabled explicit schemes.

```
app.UseOpenApi(configure => configure.PostProcess = (document, _) => document.Schemes = null);
```

From the specification:

> If schemes are not specified, the scheme used to serve the API specification will be used for API calls.